# oracle datatype

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Is there any data type greater than CLOB in oracle

Comment: I initially understood this question as a statement of awe and reverence :)

Comment: Well, NCLOB is slightly more greater, or at least more ecumenical.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no bigger datatype for storage in the database.  In Oracle 11G the limit has increased from 4GB to "(4 GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE initialization parameter (8 TB to 128 TB)" - see [Oracle 11G Database Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10820/limits001.htm#i287903)

Comment: I look forward to the day people start complaining that 128TB is too small for the kinds of data we want to store in the database :)

Comment: I can understand BLOBs in GBs and TBs (video etc). The thought of 4GB+ of text is pretty mindblowing through.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean in terms of storage?  Clob is 4 gig.  Anything 'larger' (or even smaller for that matter) you should consider storing just the location/path to the resource on disk, not the resource itself.

A detailed read on [LOB design decisions](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10796/adlob_de.htm).

Comment: Good point, database is not a file system. I can't imagine the added overhead of trying to create/update/delete such large amounts of data inside a DB!

Answer (score 0):

If by greater you mean able to store more data, the answer is no.
The four large object data types BFILE, BLOB, CLOB, and NCLOB all store up to 4 GB of data.